# TypeError at /users/login/ __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a tutorial in the "Python Crash course" Book.

The tutorial is about creating a "Learning Log" Webapp with Django. The idea of the app is to allow users to: 1. create "Topics" they have learned about 2. add "Entries" to those Topics, describing details they have learned specific to those topics

I am currently stuck at the login page and receive an Error, when I run

http://localhost:8000/users/login/

urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    # Importing the default login view provided by Django
    from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
    from .import views 
    app_name = 'users'
    urlpatterns =[
    # Login page
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView , {'template_name':'users/login.html'},name = 'login'), 
                 ]
```

login.html

```
    {% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

    {% block content %}
    {% if form.errors %}
    <p> Your username and password didn't match.Please try again. </p>
    {% endif %}

    <form method="post" action="{%url 'users:login' %}">
    {%csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button name="submit">log in</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{%url 'learning_logs:index' %}"/>
    </form>


   {% endblock content %}
```

base.html

```
    <p>
      <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a> -
      <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics'%}">Topics</a> -
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        Hello,{{user.username}}.
     {% else %}
       <a href="{% url 'users:login' %}">log in</a>
     {% endif %}
   </p>

   {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: `url(r'^login/$', LoginView ,...` => `url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view() , ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LoginView` is a class-based view, you use the [**`.as_view(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) to use it in the `urls.py`. You can pass the `template_name` as parameter in the `.as_view(…)`:

```
url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
```